# Why I'm getting unexpected results of VARCHAR comparison?

Tags: java, db2, ibm-midrange, weblogic12c, db2-400

I'm executing a sentence like this.

```
fld1 VARCHAR(5);

Select * from MyTable where fld1 = 'HELLOWORLD';
```

In the table there is only fld1='HELLO', for some reason the result set give me as result rows that fld1='HELLO'.

If fld1 is VARCHAR 5, apparently is cutting the value of 'HELLOWORLD' why the query not take all the value literally?

My Method:

```
public void Consulta(){
    COB_ConexionModulo connPool = null;
    COB_ResultadoConexion rc    = null;
    Connection con      = null;
    StringBuffer sbQry = new StringBuffer();
    PreparedStatement pstm  = null;
    ResultSet rs            = null;
    COB_Utils util = new COB_Utils();

    try {
        connPool    = COB_ConexionModulo.instance();
        rc          = connPool.getConnection();
        con         = rc.getConexion();

        if(!(con == null)){                                                           
            sbQry = new StringBuffer("SELECT NAME FROM TEST.MYTABLE WHERE NAME = ?");

            pstm = con.prepareStatement(sbQry.toString());
            pstm.setString(1, "HELLOWORLD");

            util.setInicioEjecucion();
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
            util.imprimeTiempoEjecucion(MSINF,sbQry.toString());  

            while (rs.next()){
                System.err.println(rs.getString("NAME"));
            }
        } else {
            logger.info(MSINF + "No hay conexion");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(MSERR + "Consulta()_" + e);
    }finally {
        try {if (con != null) {con.close();con = null;}} catch (SQLException sqle) {con = null;}
    }
}
```

[Images in order:
1.- Table Script
2.- Table Values
3.- Query Result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RENfO.png)

Comment: What you describe should not happen (and in fact it does not when I try to reproduce it using SQL). You may want to create and post a _complete_ minimal example to demonstrate this behaviour, as well as mention your DB2 version and platform. I suspect an error in your Java code.

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver

Comment: Looks like there is a deficiency in the driver. The standard DB2 JCC driver throws an exception if the bind parameter value is truncated. @CRPence is right about the cause and solution.

Comment: Apparently yes, already tested with 2 different web servers IBM WebSphere Application Server, 6.0.2.37 and WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.0.0 using the same driver and the result was identic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall the same effect; diagnosed with a warning, the sqlstate='01004' "The value of a string was truncated when assigned to another string data type with a shorter length." on OPEN.

I do not recall for sure what was the documentation I read, as the reason for which I made a change, but for the parameter marker to properly represent the larger string values and thus avoid the issue [i.e. to prevent the selection of the shorter values], I coded essentially, what would be for the OP [though adjusting `25` to whatever is desired; anything six or greater would suffice whilst the DDL remains NAME VARCHAR(5)]:

```
"SELECT NAME FROM TEST.MYTABLE WHERE NAME = CAST( ? AS VARCHAR(25) )"
```

Or of course, the less preferable:

```
"SELECT NAME FROM TEST.MYTABLE WHERE CAST( NAME AS VARCHAR(25) ) = ?"
```

**30-Sep-2016 Addendum**:
The documentation for the `PREPARE` explains the usage shown in the OP as specifying an *untyped parameter marker* for which "The data type of an untyped parameter marker is provided by **context**." The untyped parameter marker in the predicate of the `SELECT` statement from the OP `… where FLD1 = ?` is established as the same data type as the FLD1 column, which was revealed as `FLD1 VARCHAR(5)`. The `OPEN` and `EXECUTE` documentation, each explains the details of how the **Parameter marker replacement** is effected.  I will paraphrase some text from the docs here, for convenience, but also include three doc links following that:

> Given the Parameter Marker **`P`**, the value of the corresponding variable **`V`** is assigned to the target variable created for `P` using **storage assignment rules** as described in [Assignments and comparisons](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzch2bas.htm?view=kc). **However**, unlike noted with those storage assignment rules, **if** `V` is a string, then the value assigned to the target variable for `P` when the statement is executed, will be **truncated** (***without an error***) whenever that string-value is longer than the length attribute of the target variable for `P`; **or**, whenever that string-value is shorter than the length attribute of the target variable for `P`, the value for `P` is padded with blanks.

In each doc reference below, search for any of *Parameter Marker*, *cast*, or *Notes* to get to the most specific details; currently the details can be found in the *Notes* section:

[IBM i 7.2->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Statements->PREPARE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzpreph2.htm)

[IBM i 7.2->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Statements->EXECUTE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhexeqt.htm)

[IBM i 7.2->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Statements->OPEN](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhopen.htm)

Comment: Thank You CRPence I appreciate your help.

Comment: For the record: If anyone understands the scenario to be a defect [with the driver], then please do not consider *my experience* [with no link to any actual docs supporting that as a requirement] as evidence the effect is non-defect. What I did in my own code might be nothing more than a *circumvention* whereby perhaps the correct behavior is what Mustaccio first alluded in a comment to the OP; i.e. I might mis-remember that the doc had directed me to do so.

Comment: Somewhat similar (related?) -- [APAR SE26512](http://m.ibm.com/http/www-912.ibm.com/n_dir/nas4apar.nsf/ALLAPARS/SE26512) -- where CASTing parameter markers to appropriate data type is a circumvention.

Comment: That APAR was specific to the sqlcode=-418 effect with PREPARE, which, although similar for what is a circumvention, IMO is quite different issue.  Anyhow, I took the time to find a doc reference; I will edit and add that to my answer. [IBM i 7.2->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Statements->OPEN->"Parameter Marker Replacement"](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhopen.htm) See also the *same* docs for the EXECUTE statement.

Comment: The _root cause_ of this is expected behaviour. When the statement is prepared the database does not have the information about the possible future parameters' data types, so it derives the type for the parameter from the value on other side of the operator, that is, the database column. If you know the parameter data types may not match the column data type, the correct (and only) way to provide the data type information to the query compiler is by means of an explicit `CAST`, so this is not "circumvention". The correct driver behaviour though should be to throw an exception if...

Comment: (cont.) .. the parameter value is being truncated when bound. It appears that the IBM i Access JDBC driver behaves incorrectly. In either case, using `CAST` is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score -1):

"HELLO" is 5 chars in length which is what is stored in the DB because NAME is defined as VARCHAR(5). The remaining if formation is "trimmed"/"Dropped"/"Discarded" thus "World" does not exist form the DB's point of view.